# Manipulating Dataframes with pandas (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Python 2.7.11 // Pandas 0.18.1

I have a made up dataset (csv) to practice with for an imaginary liquor store with 250 items. The columns cover 'Brewery', 'Label', 'Year', 'Store Price', 'MSRP', 'Supplier Price', and a few others. However for this question, the relevant pieces are the Brewery and the Store Price (current price that is queried at checkout).

```
         Brewery  Store Price
104  Glenfiddich       109.99
105  Glenfiddich        89.99
108  Glenfiddich       114.99
110  Glenfiddich        99.99
119  Glenfiddich       169.99
```

If I were running a sale on Glenfiddich, I could locate the Glenfiddich items with something like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('liquorStore.csv')    
df.Brewery.str.contains('Glenfiddich')
```

I know how to find the Glenfiddich products but I do not know how to alter values of the row within the dataframe. For instance, I want to:

1. Find 'Glenfiddich' items
2. Adjust 'Store Price' to reflect a sale/new price (e.g. 10% off)

Note: I am just doing this to practice with **pandas**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for select and then multiple by `0.9`:

```
df.loc[df.Brewery == 'Glenfiddich', 'Store Price'] *= .9
```

Sample:

```
print (df)
         Brewery  Store Price
104  Glenfiddich       109.99
105  Glenfiddich        89.99
120      Another       100.00

df.loc[df.Brewery == 'Glenfiddich', 'Store Price'] *= .9
print (df)
         Brewery  Store Price
104  Glenfiddich       98.991
105  Glenfiddich       80.991
120      Another      100.000
```

Another possible solution is use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df['Store Price'] = df['Store Price'].mask(df.Brewery == 'Glenfiddich',
                                           df['Store Price'] * .9)
print (df)
         Brewery  Store Price
104  Glenfiddich       98.991
105  Glenfiddich       80.991
120      Another      100.000
```

Comment: Yes, It is another solution, but if check [here](http://tomaugspurger.github.io/modern-1.html) `The rough rule is any time you see back-to-back square brackets, ][, you're in asking for trouble. Replace that with a .loc[..., ...] and you'll be set.`